# Error message in my excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I gave a formula like

`IF(N3=0,"N/A",IF(Q3=0,IF(M3<=N3,"FAIL","PASS")),IF(M3>=O3,”PASS”,”FAIL”),0)`

and its  showing error message as "To many arguments for this function".

Comment: What's the final `,0` for?

Comment: to complete the syntax. is it not required?

Comment: No, `IF()` has 3 parameters (comparison, true value, false value): why did you think it needed more?

Answer (score 2):

You can always break up your formula in a text editor like I've done below.
There you see outermost `IF` has 5 parameters.

```
IF(
  N3=0,
  "N/A",
  IF(
    Q3=0,
    IF(
      M3<=N3,
      "FAIL",
      "PASS"
    )
  ),
  IF(
    M3>=O3,
    ”PASS”,
    ”FAIL”
  ),
  0
)
```

Comment: Will this formula work?

Comment: no it will not work, IF can have maximum of 3 parameters. That's all I could help until now. To fix it I would need to know what it should do. (please don't explain it here, but update your question).